# Using Xamarin MvvmCross helper plugins without naming conventions

Tags: xamarin, naming-conventions, mvvmcross

I liked the mvvmcross helper plugins as "Location, Accelerometer, .." and wanted to use them without being forced to follow the mvvmcross naming conventions as this is not working fine in some cases.

I noticed that: for Location plugin we need to have an "IMvxLocationWatcher"  parameter to be sent to the constructor and this object can't be generated manually .. It seems that the view passes this automatically to the viewmodel by using naming conventions.

Is their anyway to use these plugins without the naming conventions?

Comment: What do you mean by naming conventions? You mean using the IoC? Why don't you want to use this pattern? You can always create the object using Mvx.Resolve<Type> in you case Mvx.Resolve<IMvxLocationWatcher>

Comment: Can we see some example code that you are using?